# How to return multiple time series graphs in python?

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib

I have quite a large dataframe which looks something like this (this is dummy data as an example as there are more than 50 countries in the data):

```
Date          Country    Counts
----------------------------------
2019-01-21    Italy      920182
2019-01-22    Italy      82912
2019-01-23    Italy      27213
2019-01-24    Italy      28293
2019-01-21    Belgium    373732
2019-01-22    Belgium    17363
2019-01-23    Belgium    282913
2019-01-24    Belgium    2122
2019-01-21    China      234211
2019-01-22    China      1234
2019-01-23    China      13456
2019-01-24    China      8291
```

Before I was manually creating plots separately for each country in this dataframe so I could have a trend line showing the counts overtime, while also having a red line represent the total average per country. The code I used to do this for each country separately was as follows:

```
Italy_df = df.loc[df['Country'] == 'Italy'] #search for all Italy data
Italy_df['Count'].mean() #total mean for Italy

x = Italy_df['Date']
y = Italy_df['Counts']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y)
plt.axhline(y=34927.23, color='r', linestyle='--') #y is the mean calculated for all Italy counts
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.title("Weekly Sim Count average in Italy")
plt.xlabel('Week')
#plt.show()


a = '2020-01-13' #Key dates area
b = '2020-02-10'

plt.axvspan(a, b, color='gray', alpha=0.2, lw=0)
plt.plot(x, y, color='blue') #trend line over time
plt.show()
```

The plot that is returned for Italy looks something like this, I would like this same graph style to be returned for every country in my data set separately:
[image]

In the plots, the key dates highlighted in the grey box will remain the same for all countries however 1) the red line will change according to the countries mean and 2) The blue line will also change to represent counts.

Instead of me repeating this code to create a plot for every country, is there a way I could create a loop that would create these plots separately for all countries in the dataframe? This would save me so much time :)

Many thanks

Comment: What would you do with the `mean` line in this case, since you have all the countries in one plot.

Comment: @Erfan Hi there, I would like to represent the overall average for each country as this would allow us to compare the blue trend line with the average performance for the countries separately. Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: No sorry it does not, so if you would have 30 countries, you would have 30 average lines through your plot,which would make it unreadable.

Comment: @Erfan I was hoping to have separate graphs returned for every country in the dataset. I have edited my question as I feel like the last part caused some confusion :) My plan was to print separate graphs (with the example shown in the question) for each country in the data. Instead of me having to manually create these graphs, I was hoping if there was a way to loop a code to print the graphs together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below should plot all the time series for each unique value in `Country`.

Edit: the loop below now generates a new figure for each unique value in `Country`.

```
a = datetime(2019, 1, 22) #Key dates area
b = datetime(2019, 1, 23)

for _, d in df.set_index('Date').groupby('Country'):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    d['Counts'].plot()
    plt.axhline(y=d['Counts'].mean(), color='r', linestyle='--')
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    plt.title(f"Weekly Sim Count for {d['Country'].iat[0]}")
    plt.xlabel('Week')


    plt.axvspan(a, b, color='gray', alpha=0.2, lw=0)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I think I incorrectly worded my question so I edited it :( What I was hoping was to print various graphs for each country separately so that this would allow me to have separate plots

Comment: @RSem I've edited my answer to loop through the countries and generate new figures for each country.